# how do i annualize the mean of my monthly returns?

Tags: mean, descriptive-statistics, finance

I'm getting really f'd up since two hours and almost deleted all of my code since this doesn't make sense to me.

I got simple returns.

I want to calculate the annualized mean.

This would be my definition:

(1+mean(simplerets))^12-1

However, the paper im replicating is doing this:

mean(simplerets)*12

I thought maybe they are using log returns, but: since i'm replicating other results from their paper, like value of 1$ investment over a period, it doesn't seem like their data is log returns

Is mean(simplerets)*12 really the right way to calculate the annualized mean and i'm just dumb ?

Comment: The answer sort of depends on how large the monthly returns are and on what "annualized mean" is supposed to be.  Is it possible the paper *defined* it to be the arithmetic mean of the monthly returns?  Regardless, chances are they're all pretty small, maybe even less than 1% each, in which case there will be little difference between the two results.  If any one of the returns is much larger than a few percent in absolute value, though, the differences between the calculations could become important.  Which situation are you in?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! 
http://www.kentdaniel.net/papers/published/jfe_16.pdf
Thats the Paper, Table 1 presents the descriptive statistics. Data is available on his website too, but however, the mean excess returns (annualized) are pretty large, so there are definitely difference depending on the method of calculation.
Since they explicetly say that they are using log Returns for skewness, i'm 99% sure the data they published is simple returns. For example: If i replicate fig1, i get the same result by calculating the product of 1+ret. Which tells me returns are simple returns

Comment: But as i said in my Question, i get the same result for the mean excess return annualized by taking the mean of the monthly returns and multiply it by 12.